# Does a Sticky Service restart itself when process is killed?

Tags: android, service

I have a service where I return STAR_STICKy inside onStartCommand. But if there comes a force close it kills the whole process. So is the service restarted even if the whole process is killed ?

Answer (score 1):

public static final int START_STICKY
Added in API level 5

Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback.